# HTML5 input type range show range value

Tags: html, css, range

I am making a website where I want to use range slider(I know it only supports webkit browsers).

I have integrated it fully and works fine. But I would like to use a `textbox` to show the current slide value.

I mean if initially the slider is at value 5, so in text box it should show as 5, when I slide the value in text box should change.

Can I do this using only `CSS` or `html`. I want to avoid `JQuery`. Is it possible?

Comment: You can't do this without javascript.

Comment: You can *almost* do this with css using `:before`/`:after`, `content` and `attr()`, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hVvK2/). However, the :before/:after pseudo-elements actually eat up some of the slider's range (although maybe that's fixable), and most importantly, the values aren't updated if the slider is manipulated. Nevertheless, I thought it would be interesting to leave this here. It might become possible in the future.

Comment: Fixing @waldir 's solution results in http://jsfiddle.net/RjWJ8/ though it still uses javascript to update the value attribute from the property.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

This uses javascript, not jquery directly. It might help get you started.

```js
function updateTextInput(val) {
          document.getElementById('textInput').value=val; 
        }
```

```html
<input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);">
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="">
```

Comment: but is there anyway to do it without javascript or jquery?

Comment: This is from http://mobile-web-app.blogspot.com/2012/03/easy-display-value-for-of-slider-in.html , still javascript. `code`<label for="rangeinput">Range</label>
    <input id="rangeinput" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5"     onchange="rangevalue.value=value"></input>
    <output id="rangevalue">5</output>

Comment: Does anyone else think that providing a blind slider is lacking. True that providing fancy widgets is not the role of the basic standard, but showing the selected value is core to this widget, so I think that (optionally) showing the number in a basic form such as a tooltip on top of the slider handle would make for a better design.

Comment: @BaselShishani Couldn't agree more, not really sure what the thought process behind that was.

Comment: @BaselShishani: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input): "range: A control for entering a number whose exact value is not important.". In light of that assumption, showing no exact value makes sense. But in practice it will probably also be used for selecting exact values.

Comment: IE 11 shows the slider with value, in tooltip, no need to have output.

Comment: In practice, the update rate of the text seems super slow: on my machine it takes half a second to update on releasing the mouse. Is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: OK, I should use `oninput` instead of `onchange`.

Answer (score 331):

For those who are still searching for a solution without a separate javascript code. There is little easy solution without writing a javascript or jquery function:

```html
<input type="range" value="24" min="1" max="100" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value">
<output>24</output>
```

[**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/w8bw4dte/)

If you want to show the value in text box, simply change output to input.

---

**Point to note:**
It is still Javascript written within your html, we can write something like below in js to do similar thing:

```
 document.registrationForm.ageInputId.oninput = function(){
    document.registrationForm.ageOutputId.value = document.registrationForm.ageInputId.value;
 }
```

Instead of element's id, name could also be used, both are supported in modern browsers.

Comment: +1 know I know about <output>. Only problem is that E.I doesn't support it though. (W3School) http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_output

Comment: It's still javascript, and it's worse to bind oninput on form element than on input element itself.

Comment: @cuixiping, we can bind oninput on element instead of form, i just did it to show example.

Comment: Forgive this late and noob question, but how does the handler refer to rangeInput and amount by their HTML names?

Comment: @rep_movsd,  it is same as this.formName.rangeInput or this.formName.amount. Form access the elements using their name. However I am not 100% sure,

Comment: @rep_movsd, updated the answer as well, I think it should be clear now.

Comment: Interesting that modern browsers treat IDs as identifiers directly. Does it only work within forms? If it works generally then I can avoid typing $('#whatsitsname') everywhere

Comment: Yes, only within form.

Comment: I've edited the question's code to the bare minimum, stripping unnecessary code

Comment: This answer deserved rewards.

Comment: just reverified in Chrome official version 89.0.4389.114, it works fine.

Answer (score 55):

version with editable input:

```html
<form>
  <input type="range" name="amountRange" min="0" max="20" value="0" oninput="this.form.amountInput.value=this.value" />
  <input type="number" name="amountInput" min="0" max="20" value="0" oninput="this.form.amountRange.value=this.value" />
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xjxe6

Comment: Replace form variables with `this.nextElementSibling` or `this.previousElementSibling` and replace oninput with onchange to get a version that works outside of a form. http://jsfiddle.net/Xjxe6/94/

Comment: fantastic answer!

Answer (score 40):

an even better way would be to catch the input event on the input itself 
rather than on the whole form (performance wise) :

```
<input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="20" value="0"
       oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">                                                       

<output id="amount" name="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/L10r5zvv/1/) (with the `id` added as per Ryan's comment).

Comment: In Firefox 27, this didn't work for me until I added `id="amount"` for the output, too.

Comment: this should work without id:
`oninput="this.form.amount.value=this.value"`

Comment: this works but how do I get to current value and show it when the page refreshes? :-/

Answer (score 21):

If you want your current value to be displayed beneath the slider and moving along with it, try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MySliderValue</title>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>MySliderValue</h1>

  <div style="position:relative; margin:auto; width:90%">
    <span style="position:absolute; color:red; border:1px solid blue; min-width:100px;">
    <span id="myValue"></span>
    </span>
    <input type="range" id="myRange" max="1000" min="0" style="width:80%"> 
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var myRange = document.querySelector('#myRange');
var myValue = document.querySelector('#myValue');
var myUnits = 'myUnits';
var off = myRange.offsetWidth / (parseInt(myRange.max) - parseInt(myRange.min));
var px =  ((myRange.valueAsNumber - parseInt(myRange.min)) * off) - (myValue.offsetParent.offsetWidth / 2);

  myValue.parentElement.style.left = px + 'px';
  myValue.parentElement.style.top = myRange.offsetHeight + 'px';
  myValue.innerHTML = myRange.value + ' ' + myUnits;

  myRange.oninput =function(){
    let px = ((myRange.valueAsNumber - parseInt(myRange.min)) * off) - (myValue.offsetWidth / 2);
    myValue.innerHTML = myRange.value + ' ' + myUnits;
    myValue.parentElement.style.left = px + 'px';
  };
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that this type of HTML input element has one hidden feature, such as you can move the slider with left/right/down/up arrow keys when the element has focus on it. The same with Home/End/PageDown/PageUp keys.

Answer (score 19):

Shortest version without `form`, `min` or external JavaScript.

```html
<input type="range" value="0" max="10" oninput="num.value = this.value">
<output id="num">0</output>
```

**Explanation**

If you wanna retrieve the value from the `output` you commonly use an `id` that can be linked from the `oninput` instead of using `this.nextElementSibling.value` (we take advantage of something that we are already using)

Compare the example above with this valid but a little more complex and long answer:

```
<input id="num" type="range" value="0" max="100" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value">
<output>0</output>
```

With the shortest answer:

- We avoid the use of `this`, something weird in JS for newcomers
- We avoid new concept about connecting siblings in the DOM
- We avoid too much attributes in the `input` placing the `id` in the `output`

**Notes**

- In both examples we don't need to add the `min` value when equal to
  `0`
- Removing JavaScript’s `this` keyword makes it a better language

Comment: Even better, value is displayed or can be set manually:
<input type="range" class="custom-range" id="customRange22" value="50" min="0" max="100" oninput="num.value = this.value">
<input type="number" class="form-alternative ml-3" id="num" value="50" min="0" max="100" oninput="customRange22.value = this.value">

Answer (score 6):

If you're using **multiple slides**, and you can use jQuery, you can do the follow to deal with multiple sliders easily:

```js
function updateRangeInput(elem) {
  $(elem).next().val($(elem).val());
}
```

```css
input { padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ddd; color: #555; display: block; }
input[type=text] { width: 100px; }
input[type=range] { width: 400px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" min="0" max="100" oninput="updateRangeInput(this)" value="0">
<input type="text" value="0">

<input type="range" min="0" max="100" oninput="updateRangeInput(this)" value="50">
<input type="text" value="50">
```

Also, by using `oninput` on the `<input type='range'>` you'll receive events while dragging the range.

Answer (score 5):

In plain JavaScript:

```js
function displaySliderValue(eSlider){   
    eSlider.parentElement.querySelector('span').textContent = eSlider.value;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>1</span><br>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" oninput="displaySliderValue(this);">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a vanilla JS way of automatically adding the value to all range inputs without any extra HTML.

**Edit: Chrome only. I didn't realize it doesn't work with Firefox.**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]').forEach(e => {
  e.setAttribute('data-value', e.value);
  e.addEventListener('input', () => {
    e.setAttribute('data-value', e.value);
  });
});
```

```css
input[type="range"]::after {
  content: attr(data-value);
  margin-right: -50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range"><br>
<input type="range"><br>
<input type="range">
```

Answer (score 2):

For people don't care about jquery use, here is a short way without using any id

```
<label> userAvatar :
  <input type="range" name="userAvatar" min="1" max="100" value="1"
         onchange="$('~ output', this).val(value)" 
         oninput="$('~ output', this).val(value)">
  <output>1</output>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that involves (Vanilla) JavaScript, but only as a library. You habe to include it once and then all you need to do is set the appropriate `source` attribute of the number inputs.

The `source` attribute should be the `querySelectorAll` selector of the range input you want to listen to.

It even works with selectcs. And it works with multiple listeners. And it works in the other direction: change the number input and the range input will adjust. And it will work on elements added later onto the page (check https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/JzaVQg for that)

Tested in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE11

```js
;(function(){
  
  function emit(target, name) {
    var event
    if (document.createEvent) {
      event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
      event.initEvent(name, true, true);
    } else {
      event = document.createEventObject();
      event.eventType = name;
    }

    event.eventName = name;

    if (document.createEvent) {
      target.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else {
      target.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
    }    
  }

  var outputsSelector = "input[type=number][source],select[source]";
  
  function onChange(e) {
    var outputs = document.querySelectorAll(outputsSelector)
    for (var index = 0; index < outputs.length; index++) {
      var item = outputs[index]
      var source = document.querySelector(item.getAttribute('source'));
      if (source) {
        if (item === e.target) {
          source.value = item.value
          emit(source, 'input')
          emit(source, 'change')
        }

        if (source === e.target) {
          item.value = source.value
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  document.addEventListener('change', onChange)
  document.addEventListener('input', onChange)
}());
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <input name="example" type="range" max="2250000" min="-200000" value="0" step="50000">
  <input id="example-value" type="number" max="2250000" min="-200000" value="0" step="50000" source="[name=example]">
  <br>

  <input name="example2" type="range" max="2240000" min="-160000" value="0" step="50000">
  <input type="number" max="2240000" min="-160000" value="0" step="50000" source="[name=example2]">
  <input type="number" max="2240000" min="-160000" value="0" step="50000" source="[name=example2]">
  <br>
  
  <input name="example3" type="range" max="20" min="0" value="10" step="1">
  <select source="[name=example3]">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```
 <input min="0" max="100" id="when_change_range" type="range">
 <input type="text" id="text_for_show_range">
```

and in **jQuery** section :

```
 $('#when_change_range').change(function(){
 document.getElementById('text_for_show_range').value=$(this).val();
  });
```

Comment: Excellent !!! , but note that you put value='20' more than the max ='10' , so it gets an error .

Answer (score -2):

```html
<form name="registrationForm">
    <input type="range" name="ageInputName" id="ageInputId" value="24" min="1" max="10" onchange="getvalor(this.value);" oninput="ageOutputId.value = ageInputId.value">
    <input type="text" name="ageOutputName" id="ageOutputId"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: getvalor is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 12,
  "colno": 169
}

Answer (score -5):

if you still looking for the answer you can use input type="number" in place of type="range" min max work if it set in that order:
1-name
2-maxlength
3-size
4-min
5-max
just copy it

```
<input  name="X" maxlength="3" size="2" min="1" max="100" type="number" />
```

Comment: This is just wrong, it does not do what the topic starter requested.