# HTML5 range - unsupported pseudo: range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I got a rather simple question. I use the HTML5 range slider type: `<input type="range">` and I want to trigger it via jQuery.

I used the following code:

```
$("form input:range").each(function () {
    // Do something
});
```

For some reason I get the following error:

> !
>   Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: range

Perhaps important: I use **jquery-1.12.1.min.js**.

Does anyone now why this is and how I could solve this?

Comment: The error states the exact issue, there is no `:range` selector in jQuery.

Comment: Please read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004723/html5-input-type-range-show-range-value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery("input[type=range]")
```

`:` is for getting some kind of meta information, usually related to what the user is doing with the element.

For example: `:hover` only applies to elements the user has placed the cursor over and `:visible` is elements the user can see.

**EDIT**

Pranav C Balan's answer better explains what is going on: [HTML5 range - unsupported pseudo: range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540508/html5-range-unsupported-pseudo-range/#37540546)

Answer (score 5):

There is no `:range` pseudo selector in css or jQuery. Instead you can  use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$("form input[type='range']").each(function () {
    // Do something
});
```

---

For all supported selectors list visit : **[JQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use attribute equals selector:

```
jQuery("input[type=range]")
```

There's use of [:in-range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:in-range) or [:out-of-range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:out-of-range) css selector that you can use for min and max value range:

```
$("form input:in-range").each(function () {
    // Do something
});
```

But alas! There's no `:range` selector.