# Shifting Qualtrics sliders to the left/right

Tags: java, html

I am trying to design a real effort task in qualtrics, where I need the sliders to be offset from one another. It roughly should look like follows:

[sliders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCzAh.png)

I did not find any HTML codes regarding slider elements, only with respect to the question text-box.

Some help would be much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to try with positioning:

```css
input[type="range"] {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.a-little-left {
  position: relative;
  left: -5px
}

.more-left {
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="a-little-left" id="range-one"><label for="range-one">0</label><br/>
<input type="range" class="more-left" id="range-two"><label for="range-one">50</label>
```

Or maybe with negative `margin` values:

```css
input[type="range"],
label {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
}

.a-little-left {
  margin-left: -5px
}

.more-left {
  margin-left: -50px
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="a-little-left" id="range-one"><label for="range-one">0</label><br/>
<input type="range" class="more-left" id="range-two"><label for="range-one">50</label>
```

## So, which one should you choose?

Positioning with `position: relative` moves objects **after** they've been placed:
[image: an example of positioning with position: relative]

On the other hand, positioning with `margin` physically moves the input to the left. The choice is yours.

The problem that you may get from above solutions is that it *can* overflow your body. This can be easily fixed by setting a `left-margin` or a `position` to all your `input`, like I did.

Also, note the `input[type="range"]` selector, so that it only select your `range` sliders.

Comment: Works great, thank you very much! Since these are not the original qualtrics sliders, I need to code the scoring myself. Sliders positioned at value 50 should account for one score point and at any other value for zero points. The total score should be saved in an embedded data field. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Here is a hint : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004723/html5-input-type-range-show-range-value#18936328

Comment: If you're still having problems, feel free to open a new question :)