# How can I do to display the current value with an input of type range

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello I have some input of type range on my code written with HTML like this :

this is my input :

```
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
```

But I can't see the current value... How can I do to display it ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: refer this:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004723/html5-input-type-range-show-range-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 input type range show range value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004723/html5-input-type-range-show-range-value)

Comment: Why is this tagged with `PHP`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [value property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) of the input element:

```js
function getValue() {

  let value = document.querySelector('#myRange').value

  // here we are logging the value in the console
  console.log(value)

}
```

```html
<button onclick="getValue()">See value</button>

<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code, use **value** property of you range input  to get the current value:

```js
var res =  document.getElementById('currentValue');
    var rangeInput = document.getElementById('myRange');
    res.innerHTML = rangeInput.value;
    
rangeInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    res.innerHTML = e.target.value
})
```

```html
 <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
<div id="currentValue"></div>
```

Comment: Thx you but where do I put this `var res =  document.getElementById('currentValue');
    var rangeInput = document.getElementById('myRange');
    res.innerHTML = rangeInput.value;
    
rangeInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    res.innerHTML = e.target.value
})`

Comment: You can put it in your javascript file. Do you have one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function updateValue(val) {
          document.getElementById('textInput').value=val; 
 
        }
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange" onchange="updateValue(this.value);">
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="">
```