# How to get range input value on input box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using js to get value from the range slider. now I wanted to show that in the input box.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
 <input type="range" min="1" max="10"  name="ans" class="slider" id="myRange">
 value:<p><span id="demo"></p>
```

NEED THE VALUE TO BE SHOWN IN THE INPUT BOX

Comment: There is no "input box" in your code. There's a `span`, which does show the value. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004723/html5-input-type-range-show-range-value Does this question answer your question?

Comment: It is same as how you are doing with span. Only difference is you have to use `value` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: which input box did you mean?

Comment: ```<span>``` does not have matching closing ```<span>``` ?

Comment: leave the span tag. add html input box. and i wanted to show the values on input box same as i get from "id=demo" - 'span' tag or 'p' tag. thankyou

Comment: still can't find the solution checkout my code on code pen -> https://codepen.io/ajitstark/pen/jONKeej?editors=1010#0

Answer (score 2):

You just need some minor changes.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var inputItem = document.getElementById("outputPounds");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
weightConverter(slider.value);
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  weightConverter(slider.value);
}

function weightConverter(valNum) {
  inputItem.value=valNum*2.2046;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="200" name="ans" class="slider" 
 id="myRange">

 <p class="agecls">Weight:<span id="demo" style="text-decoration:underline" 
 oninput="weightConverter(this.value)" 
 onchange="weightConverter(this.value)"></span></p>

 <p>Pounds: <input type="text" value="0" id="outputPounds"></p>
```

Comment: still can't find the solution checkout my code on code pen -> https://codepen.io/ajitstark/pen/jONKeej?editors=1010#0

Comment: Please run the above code. I have updated it. Please let me know if you are still getting an issue. @teenagevampire

Answer (score 0):

Please update the code by this

```
    <input type="range" min="1" max="200" name="ans" class="slider" id="myRange">
    <p class="agecls">Weight:<span id="demo" style="text-decoration:underline"></span></p>
    <p>Pounds: <span id="outputPounds"></span></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;
    weightConverter(slider.value)
    slider.oninput = function() {
      output.innerHTML = this.value;
      weightConverter(this.value)
    }


    function weightConverter(valNum) {
      document.getElementById("outputPounds").innerHTML=valNum*2.2046;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: still can't find the solution checkout my code on code pen -> https://codepen.io/ajitstark/pen/jONKeej?editors=1010#0

Comment: I have updated the code please try updated code again . It would be solve your prob . if still any issue please let me know thank you :)

Comment: works fine. i'm just updated little bit for two decimal places. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Your entire code could be simplified to a function which reads the input value and updates each of the two places where you want to display the value in either metric or imperial system.

Placing everything inside one function enables you to bind the execution of this function on two events:

**a)** on `window.onload` event (so the conversion and display are done when page loads);
**b)** on `input.oninput` event, so they are also done when you slide. Note that `change` event only fires once you release the slider while `input` event fires when a slider value input has been detected, irrespective of input method (keyboard, mouse, touch, etc...).

Working example:

```js
const updateValues = function() {
  let inputValue = document.querySelector('#myRange').value;
  document.querySelector('#outputKg').innerHTML = inputValue;
  document.querySelector('#outputLbs').innerHTML = Math.round(inputValue * 220.462262) / 100;
}
window.onload = updateValues;
document.querySelector('#myRange').oninput = updateValues;
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="200" name="ans" class="slider" id="myRange">
<p>Weight: <span id="outputKg"></span></p>
<p>Pounds: <span id="outputLbs"></span></p>
```